# Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter. iOS Swift. How do I save my Chest Data?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

This is a SwiftUI problem where "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter". Basically I am trying to access a variable outside of my init class before/during init within self. How else am I suppose to save my ChestData? Here I am trying to create a modular view. Where the button's images and onclick effects are all stored in an array.

Supporting Structs

```
struct ShopButton: View {
    let imageName: String
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/8)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDisplay: View {
    let imageName: String
    let action: (() -> Void)?
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var body: some View {
        if let action = action {
            Button(action: action) {
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/8)
            }
        } else {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/8)
        }
    }
}
```

View Model and main View

```
class ShopViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @State var presentChest:Bool = false
    var chest:Chest? = nil
}

struct ShopView: View {
    // Sample shop items data
    var goldItems:[ShopItem] = []
    var gemItems:[ShopItem] = []
    var chestItems:[ShopItem] = []
    @ObservedObject var viewModel:ShopViewModel
    
    init() {
        let purchaseHandler = PurchaseHandler()
        viewModel = ShopViewModel()
        var resultChest:Chest?
        
        self.goldItems = [
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "1000gold", gemImageName: "60gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: {
                handleGemForGoldTransaction(gemsToSpend: 60, goldToIncrease: 1000) { success, message in
                    if success
                    {
                    } else
                    {
                        // display error
                    }
                }
            }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "5000gold", gemImageName: "320gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: {
                handleGemForGoldTransaction(gemsToSpend: 320, goldToIncrease: 5000) { success, message in
                    if success
                    {
                    } else
                    {
                        // display error
                    }
                }
            }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "10000gold", gemImageName: "500gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: {
                handleGemForGoldTransaction(gemsToSpend: 500, goldToIncrease: 10000) { success, message in
                    if success
                    {
                    } else
                    {
                        // display error
                    }
                }
            }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "50000gold", gemImageName: "2250gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: {
                handleGemForGoldTransaction(gemsToSpend: 2250, goldToIncrease: 50000) { success, message in
                    if success
                    {
                    } else
                    {
                        // display error
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
        
        self.gemItems = [
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "100gems", gemImageName: "0.99", itemAction: nil, gemAction: {
                print("0.99$ tapped")
                purchaseHandler.purchaseProduct(purchaseOption: .ninetyNineCents) { success, message in
                    if success {
                        // Handle the successful purchase
                        handleGemPurchaseForMoney(gemsToIncrease: 100, moneySpent: 0.99) { success, message in
                            if success {
                                // handle gems increasing
                            } else
                            {
                                print(message)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle the purchase failure
                        // Display an error message, if needed
                    }
                }
            }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "1200gems", gemImageName: "9.99", itemAction: nil, gemAction: {
                print("9.99$ Tapped")
                purchaseHandler.purchaseProduct(purchaseOption: .nineNintyNine) { success, message in
                    if success {
                        // Handle the successful purchase
                        handleGemPurchaseForMoney(gemsToIncrease: 1200, moneySpent: 9.99) { success, message in
                            if success {
                                // handle gems increasing
                            } else
                            {
                                print(message)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle the purchase failure
                        // Display an error message, if needed
                    }
                }
            }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "6500gems", gemImageName: "49.99", itemAction: nil, gemAction: { 
                print("49.99$ Tapped")
                purchaseHandler.purchaseProduct(purchaseOption: .fortyNineNintyNine) { success, message in
                    if success {
                        // Handle the successful purchase
                        handleGemPurchaseForMoney(gemsToIncrease: 6500, moneySpent: 49.99) { success, message in
                            if success {
                                // handle gems increasing
                            } else
                            {
                                print(message)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle the purchase failure
                        // Display an error message, if needed
                    }
                }
            }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "14000gems", gemImageName: "99.99", itemAction: nil, gemAction: { 
                print("99.99$ Tapped")
                purchaseHandler.purchaseProduct(purchaseOption: .ninetyNineCents) { success, message in
                    if success {
                        // Handle the successful purchase
                        handleGemPurchaseForMoney(gemsToIncrease: 14000, moneySpent: 99.99) { success, message in
                            if success {
                                // handle gems increasing
                            } else
                            {
                                print(message)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle the purchase failure
                        // Display an error message, if needed
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
        
        self.chestItems = [
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "explorerChest", gemImageName: "250gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: { 
                print("250gemButto tapped")
                **handleChestItemsBoughtForChest(chestType: .explorer, gemsToSpend: 250)** { success, message in // Issue here
                    if success {
                        
                    } else
                    {
                        print("Error, Enable to purchase chest.")
                    }
                }
            }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "masterChest", gemImageName: "750gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: { print("750gemButton Tapped") }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "epicChest", gemImageName: "2500gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: { print("2500gemButton Tapped") }),
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "legendaryChest", gemImageName: "5000gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: { print("5000gemButton Tapped") })
        ]
        
        func handleGemForGoldTransaction(gemsToSpend: Int, goldToIncrease: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void) {
            if NetworkMonitor.shared.isConnected {
                SettingsHandler.shared.playerHandler.spendGems(by: gemsToSpend) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Handle the error, return false and an error message
                        completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        // Gems spent successfully, now increase gold
                        SettingsHandler.shared.playerHandler.increaseGold(by: goldToIncrease) { error in
                            if let error = error {
                                // Display error - gold increase failed
                                completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
                            } else {
                                // Transaction successful
                                completion(true, "Transaction successful")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // No network connection
                completion(false, "No network connection")
            }
        }
        
        func handleChestItemsBoughtForChest(chestType:ChestType, gemsToSpend:Int, completion: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void)
        {
            if SettingsHandler.shared.playerHandler.user.gems > gemsToSpend
            {
                switch chestType
                {
                case .bronze:
                    print("Error, user cannot purchase bronze chest")
                case .silver:
                    print("Error, user cannot purchase silver chest")
                case .explorer:
                    RewardsHandler().generateChestForAnteAndUser(ante: 12) { chest, error in
                        
                        if error == nil
                        {
                            resultChest = chest
                        } else
                        {
                            print("Chest failed to generate")
                        }
                    }
                case .master:
                    RewardsHandler().generateChestForAnteAndUser(ante: 16) { chest, error in
                        
                        if error == nil
                        {
                            resultChest = chest
                        } else
                        {
                            print("Chest failed to generate")
                        }
                    }
                case .epic:
                    RewardsHandler().generateChestForAnteAndUser(ante: 20) { chest, error in
                        
                        if error == nil
                        {
                            resultChest = chest
                        } else
                        {
                            print("Chest failed to generate")
                        }
                    }
                case .legendary:
                    RewardsHandler().generateChestForAnteAndUser(ante: 24) { chest, error in
                        
                        if error == nil
                        {
                            resultChest = chest
                        } else
                        {
                            print("Chest failed to generate")
                        }
                    }
                }
                viewModel.chest = resultChest // This is causing the issue
                viewModel.presentChest = true // This is causing the issue. I know why, but what is the alternative?

            } else
            {
                completion(false,"Not enough Gems")
                print("Not enough Gems.")
            }
            
        }
        
        func handleGemPurchaseForMoney(gemsToIncrease:Int, moneySpent:Double, completion: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void)
        {
            if NetworkMonitor.shared.isConnected {
                SettingsHandler.shared.playerHandler.buyGems(amountPurchased: moneySpent) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        // Handle the error, return false and an error message
                        completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        // Gems spent successfully, now increase Gems
                        SettingsHandler.shared.playerHandler.increaseGems(by: gemsToIncrease) { error in
                            if let error = error {
                                // Display error - gold increase failed
                                completion(false, error.localizedDescription)
                            } else {
                                // Transaction successful
                                completion(true, "Transaction successful")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // No network connection
                completion(false, "No network connection")
            }
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if viewModel.presentChest == true && viewModel.chest != nil
            {
                RewardsView(isPresented: .constant(true), rewardData: RewardsHandler().getRewardsView(chest: viewModel.chest!), chestType: viewModel.chest!.chestType)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            } else
            {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("Shop")
                            .font(Font.custom("Bebas-Regular", size: 80))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("Gold")
                            .font(Font.custom("Bebas-Regular", size: 50))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex:"#DA35AA"))
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(goldItems, id: \.gemImageName) { item in
                                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                    ItemDisplay(imageName: item.itemImageName, action: item.itemAction)
                                    ShopButton(imageName: item.gemImageName, action: item.gemAction)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Text("Gem")
                            .font(Font.custom("Bebas-Regular", size: 50))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex:"#D61519"))
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(gemItems, id: \.gemImageName) { item in
                                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                    ItemDisplay(imageName: item.itemImageName, action: item.itemAction)
                                    ShopButton(imageName: item.gemImageName, action: item.gemAction)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Text("Chest")
                            .font(Font.custom("Bebas-Regular", size: 50))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex:"#E89F33"))
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(chestItems, id: \.gemImageName) { item in
                                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                    ItemDisplay(imageName: item.itemImageName, action: item.itemAction)
                                    ShopButton(imageName: item.gemImageName, action: item.gemAction)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width) // Set your desired maximum width
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is that handleChestItemsBoughtForChest is a function that will **generate a chest object that needs to be saved** somewhere and on successful chest creation, I need to **set presentChest to true** so that in UI we can detect that change and present a chest and it's view/animation to the user.

My only solution I can think of is to instead of using the method of creating an array of ShopItem. I create them individually for this specific case because it has to affect view someway. If any1 has a better alternative that fits in this modular blueprint please share.

Minimal Example

```
import SwiftUI
// Data model for shop items
struct ShopItem {
    let itemImageName: String
    let gemImageName: String
    let itemAction: (() -> Void)?
    let gemAction: () -> Void
}

class ShopViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @State var presentChest:Bool = false
    var chest:Chest? = nil
}

struct ShopView: View {
    // Sample shop items data
    var goldItems:[ShopItem] = []
    var gemItems:[ShopItem] = []
    var chestItems:[ShopItem] = []
    @ObservedObject var viewModel:ShopViewModel
    
    init() {
        let purchaseHandler = PurchaseHandler()
        viewModel = ShopViewModel()
        var resultChest:Chest?
        
        self.chestItems = [
            ShopItem(itemImageName: "explorerChest", gemImageName: "250gemButton", itemAction: nil, gemAction: { 
                print("250gemButto tapped")
                handleChestItemsBoughtForChest(chestType: .explorer, gemsToSpend: 250) { success, message in
                    if success {
                        
                    } else
                    {
                        print("Error, Enable to purchase chest.")
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
        
        func handleChestItemsBoughtForChest(chestType:ChestType, gemsToSpend:Int, completion: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void)
        {
            if SettingsHandler.shared.playerHandler.user.gems > gemsToSpend
            {
                switch chestType
                {
                case .explorer:
                    RewardsHandler().generateChestForAnteAndUser(ante: 12) { chest, error in
                        
                        if error == nil
                        {
                            resultChest = chest
                        } else
                        {
                            print("Chest failed to generate")
                        }
                    }
                }
                //viewModel.chest = resultChest // issue here when trying to save the information outside of init.
                //viewModel.presentChest = true
            } else
            {
                completion(false,"Not enough Gems")
                print("Not enough Gems.")
            }
            
        }
        
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if viewModel.presentChest == true && viewModel.chest != nil
            {
                RewardsView(isPresented: .constant(true), rewardData: RewardsHandler().getRewardsView(chest: viewModel.chest!), chestType: viewModel.chest!.chestType)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            } else
            {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("Shop")
                            .font(Font.custom("Bebas-Regular", size: 80))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Text("Chest")
                            .font(Font.custom("Bebas-Regular", size: 50))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex:"#E89F33"))
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(chestItems, id: \.gemImageName) { item in
                                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                                    ItemDisplay(imageName: item.itemImageName, action: item.itemAction)
                                    ShopButton(imageName: item.gemImageName, action: item.gemAction)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width) // Set your desired maximum width
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ShopButton: View {
    let imageName: String
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/8)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDisplay: View {
    let imageName: String
    let action: (() -> Void)?
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    var body: some View {
        if let action = action {
            Button(action: action) {
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/8)
            }
        } else {
            Image(imageName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/7, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/8)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not do all that stuff in the `init()`.
 Move all of that code to a function, or class etc... then use `.onAppear {...}`.
 Note that you should use `@StateObject var viewModel = ShopViewModel()`
 and again not in the `init()`. My suggestion is restructure your code, what you currently have is bad practice.

Comment: Have a look at this **official** link, for how to manage data in your ios16 app: [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)
 and for ios17 [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).
 
 Note, you cannot have `@State var presentChest:Bool = false` in a class,
 `@State` is only for `Views`. Do some more tutorials.

Comment: Can you [create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I had initially done this but there was a separate issue. Something about class not initialized cannot use function in variable. I would have to instead write the exact same code 4 times which did not sit well with me.

State var presentChest:Bool = false in a class, State is only for Views
Yes I understand this part. I was trying something else to mitigate the issue
Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @son I added a minimal sample. However, still quite long... its a complicated thing haha...